# preserveAspectRatio not working when embedded in HTML?

Tags: html, svg

I may be just missing something, but I have found that when SVG is embedded in an HTML document, the viewBox is obeyed but preserveAspectRatio appears to be ignored.
Here is a very simple demonstration.  Standalone SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  
       viewBox="0 0 720 960" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="720" height="960" 
         style="fill:none;stroke:red;stroke-width:10"/>
</svg>
```

Same SVG embedded in a HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SVG Embedded</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 720 960"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="720" height="960"  
       style="fill:none;stroke:red;stroke-width:10"/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is [link](http://www.geofx.com/graphics/sandbox/test_par.svg) to a demo of the SVG.  And here is a [link](http://www.geofx.com/graphics/sandbox/test_par.xhtml) to the SVG embedded in HTML.
Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/richardylewright/9b48bLpj/) to a jsfiddle of the embedded SVG (no standalone SG jsfddle since jsfiddle wraps whatever is there in HTML).
This looks like a bug to me, but hopefully I am just missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML content has no inherent height. Therefore the SVG will always use the available width, and the height is only computed afterwards. If your container has a defined height, like so:

```
<div style="position:fixed;height:100%;overflow:scroll">
    <svg...>
</div>
```

a vertical scrollbar is shown, and the horizontal space is still used.

But if you now explicitely set the svg height to 100%, the svg is scaled:

```
<div style="position:fixed;height:100%">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 720 960"
         preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="720" height="960"  
              style="fill:none;stroke:red;stroke-width:10"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I can see your point, but I would have thought that in that case, the browser would have effectively passed in innerWidth/Height and the SVG engine would have handled that just as it does for standalone SVG.  The standalone SVG works in all the browsers I tried without problems.  Your suggestion helps but in all the different browsers clip or overflow the content differently, often in odd ways.  So it is not really an acceptable result.

Comment: Keep in mind that the default value for width/height on a <svg> is 100%. - Have you found a browser where my example did not work out? In my tests, they all did.

Comment: Well, the exact example you give sort of works everywhere, except that one does see all of the rectangle without scrolling.  The whole point of "meet" is that SVG is wholly visible (fills the viewport) without scrolling.  If one sets overflow to "hidden" then part of the SVG rectangle is clipped in all browsers.  So I am still looking for a good solution.  It may be that there ISN'T one.

Comment: Did you look closely at the examples? The first one was for demonstration purposes only, the second one only uses `<div style="position:fixed;height:100%">` plus an extraneous `height="100%"` on the svg element. That second one scales the SVG to the viewport for me, no scrollbars or hidden parts.

Comment: Yes, I did.  And you're right it is _almost_ correct. One additional tweak and a caveat.  I had to change the SVG height to 98% to avoid clipping the bottom.  And even with those changes it works correctly EXCEPT if the aspect ratio of the container is narrower than the aspect ratio of the viewbox.  If the container is narrower, then it clips instead of altering scaling to reduce the height of the rendered SVG content.  Still, it is a lot closer.  Thanks for your insights. I think this is as close as it will get, so have marked the answer fixed. I also updated the jsfiddle with these changes.

Comment: Last little comment: instead of the 98%, you could also set `body { margin:0; }`, the 100% are interpreted as the window height irrespective of the fact that the body size is slightly smaller.